# Dynamic PHP Archived posts

Tags: php, html

Ok so I have looked around and cant seem to find exactly what I want to do on the web, maybe Im using the wrong terms but here is my problem. I am new at using php, but have quite a bit of experience in coding in MATLAB, so I am able to pick it up relatively easily.

I am building a website and I have some tabs for the content that opens up to the different pages that display summary's of the articles on the website. Now what I want to be able to do is to add .php articles and .php summary pages to a folder and have the website update and add them. This part I'm ok with so far I think. The next part is that I only want to display 3 summary's and then have like the page number at the bottom to go to previous articles.

So far the code I have for retrieving the tabs with the article summary's looks like this:

```
    <?php
    $pages_dir = 'pages';
    if (!empty($_GET['p']))  {
        $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
        unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);        
        $p = $_GET['p'];    
        if (in_array($p.'.php', $pages))  {
            include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Sorry, page not found.';
        }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: most people would be using a db, not flat files